# Linux + how to capture the OS disk device

Tags: linux, scripting, disk, fdisk, lsblk

we want to capture the disk device that belong to the OS ( Linux )

since each linux machine have list of disks that are not the OS , we want to capture the disk that belong to the OS

so by fdisk we can see that boot is on sda1

```
# sfdisk -l   | grep Linux
/dev/sda1   *      0+     63-     64-    512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         63+  19581-  19518- 156773376   8e  Linux LVM
```

so according to that I created the following command  , in order to capture the disk that belong to the OS ( linux )

```
# OS_DISK=` sfdisk -l   | grep Linux | awk '$2 == "*" {print $1}' | sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' `

# echo $OS_DISK    
  sda
```

seems the command do the Job

but Ifeel that this cli is too long and little clumsy

Comment: What's your defintion of "belonging to the OS"? The root partition? `/boot`/`/usr`/`/var`/… partitions (in case they're separate)? `/home` (if it is local)? All local partitions that are mounted? Or all local partitions, even if they're not mounted? There are many special cases (e.g. multiboot systems) and it isn't clear how you would like to handle those.

Comment: yes boot partitions

Comment: Regardless of the problematic definition of "the OS", there is no single, general, simple, command to get the physical device that hosts a mount point. In this specific case, supposing that you are looking for the physical disk that hosts the partition mounted as `/boot`, `lsblk -n -o PKNAME "$(findmnt -n -T /boot -o SOURCE)"` will probably work (`PKNAME` for `lsblk` is the "internal parent kernel device name").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I find the simplest command to identify the operating system disk
   to be `df /`. 
   Unfortunately, it produces a lot of output
   (by which I mean a header line and many fields),
   so you would still need to do some filtering
   to get just the device name.
2. You're right; your command is overly long and somewhat clumsy. 
   `awk` is a very powerful program; you rarely need
   to combine it with `grep` and/or `sed`,
   and having multiple `awk` commands in the same pipeline
   is almost never necessary. 
   Your pipeline can be replaced with

   ```
   sfdisk -l | awk '/Linux/ && $2 == "*" { gsub("[0-9]", "", $1); split($1, a, "/"); print a[3]; }'
   ```

   OK, it's only about a dozen *characters* shorter,
   but it's one command instead of five.

   P.S. `sed 's/[0-9]*//g'` is a slightly dangerous command. 
   Because of the `g`,
   it doesn't really make sense to have the `*` also. 
   To see what I mean, try `sed 's/[0-9]*/X/g'` with various inputs,
   and compare to `s/[0-9]/X/g` and `s/[0-9]\+/X/g`.
3. `` OS_DISK=` command ` `` can be changed
   to `OS_DISK=$(command)`,
   and the second form (with the parentheses) is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Commands `fdisk` and `sfdisk` are included in package `util-linux`. 
In the same package there is also `findmnt` command, that you can use like bellow:

```
findmnt / -no SOURCE
/dev/sda6
```